# increase resolution of preview frame

Tags: android, zxing

I changed the zxing code a little bit so in CaptureActivity.java, Bitmap barcode can be returned to my main app through an intent (I encode the bitmap using base64 and pass a string for the intent). Anyways, the problem is that barcode has a very low resolution and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to return the preview picture (barcode) with a higher resolution (or have the width and height be greater then the preview frame).

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure you can do this if the device supports a preview resolution later than the screen. The app will already do this as of tthe latest version and use a little more resolution this way. Note that the LG Optimus has a notorious bug that will prevent it from working if you do this.

You don't want tto make the reticle larger or it will induce the user to hold the barcode too close to focus.

Comment: the resolution of the preview frame seems to clam to the screen resolution (framingRectInPreview) where MAX_FRAME_WIDTH and HEIGHT and defined as 600x400. I want as much resolution as possible from the camera feed. So in DecodeHandler the width and height that are passed are that of preview frame so when decode() in DecodeHandler.java calls: PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = activity.getCameraManager().buildLuminanceSource(data, width, height); the width and height are that of preview frame. I need something much with much greater resolution - preferable one that matches camera resolution

Comment: OK. Like I said you can change it to use a larger resolution if you want which you have confirmed. What's the problem.

Comment: I can't increase it over 800x480 which is the max resolution of the preview display, if I try to make the width and height any larger zxing crossing crashes.

Comment: Then you aren't really making the complete change necessary to do what you want. You have to rewrite more to not try to enforce a smaller limit.

Comment: ok, I'll look at the library again. I thought it was android that was restricting the preview frame to the max resolution of the display (800x480). Does this mean I can set preview to be greater then the size of my preview width and height to be 1280x720 even if my screens max resolution is 800x480 in Android (not taking the zxing library into account), I asked a similar question here: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426372/grab-frame-from-video-in-android" but got a different response saying android sdk limits setPreview size to be that of screen resolution and there isn't any way of

Comment: getting byte[] data that is not the size of setPreview - sorry for the redundant questions, new to android and zxing and thanks for the continued help

Comment: The device may indeed support a preview size larger than the screen. You have to query it to see what's supported. The other answer is wrong. Try it. You need to read the code more and use the debugger maybe to understand... I don't know what you've changed so can't help much.

Comment: Thanks, the other response threw me off.

Comment: So, from what i understood, you can actually increase the resolution of the preview frame - but how much? Not more than actually camera resolution - right ? Many thanks.

Comment: Depends entirely on the device. I can't imagine it supports more pixels than in camera mode, yes.