# grab frame from video in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, yuv

I've been looking at different ways of grabbing a YUV frame from a video stream but most of what I've seen rely on getting the width and height from previewSize. However, a cell phone can shoot video at 720p but a lot of phones can only display it at a lower resolution (ie 800x480) so is it possible to grab a screen shot that's closer to 1920x1080 (if video is being shot at 720p)? Or Am i forced to use the preview resolution (800x400 on some phones)?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. *

* Conditions Apply -

- You need access to middle layer, mediaframe work to be more precise
- No, it cannot be done only through the application

Now if you want to do it at the mediaframe work level here are steps -

- Assuming you are using Froyo and above, the default mediaframe work used is StageFright
- In StageFright go to method `onVideoEvent` after a buffer is read from the `mVideoSource` use the `mVideoBuffer` to access the video frame at its original resolution

Linking this with your application -

- You will need a button in the application to indicate screen capture
- Once the user presses this button then you read the video frame from the location mentioned above and then return this buffer to the Java layer
- From here you can use the JPEG Encoder to convert the raw video frame to an image.

**EDIT:**
Re read your question, you were asking for the screen capture during recording or the camera path. Even for this there is no way to achieve this in application alone, you will have to do something similar but you will need access to `CameraSource` in the StageFright framework.

Comment: I was talking about screen capture when recording video. I'm having trouble finding resources on mVideoSource and mVideoBuffer, any advice on how to get more information on the topic. Thanks

Comment: It's at the mediaframe work level, below the java layer. If you have the android source code then it is located in this project /android/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp

Comment: if I modify the android frame word, doesn't that mean the client who needs the run my app will need to have the same version of

Comment: Yes, that means you cannot put up your application on the market

Comment: so theres no official (a way that doesn't required android to be modified) way to grab video feed of high resolution (only which is restricted to preview)? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately no, Android still needs to evolve maybe someday :)

Comment: Um, no, this is not right at all. If the device supports it, and most do, you can certainly request a preview size that is different from, and larger than, the screen size. At least, I've certainly done this in Barcode Scanner!

Comment: @SeanOwen - then perhaps you can tell us how to do this?

Comment: Call Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), get the larger size you want and call setPreviewSize()

Comment: you will not be able to maintain the aspect ratio while displaying the preview, that is acceptable?